# How do I iterate through a System.out.format line in java?

Tags: java, loops

I am writing a program to find an array of doubles, let's say it found:

`double[] dubArray = {3.5,3.5,3.7,4.3,4.5,4.5,4.5,4.7,5.0,5.5,5.5};`

Then create a counter that will print all the values from lowest to highest

```
Array.sort(dubArray); //considering the array is out of order
int finalDub = dubArray.length;
double min = dubArray[0];
double max = dubArray[finalDub - 1];

for (double i = min; i < max; i += 0.1) {
   System.out.printf("%.1f %n", i );
}
```

I need to have this code not only print through the values but also count the number of doubles and put a '$' in front of it to show the amount that double is in the array.

For example, my above code would output:

```
3.5
3.6
3.7
.
. 
.
5.3
5.4
5.5
```

But I need it to output:

```
3.5 $$
3.6
3.7 $
.
.
.
5.3 
5.4 
5.5 $$
```

How could I make the counter then be able to iterate it into the 'System.out.printf("%.1f %n", i );' line?

I'd prefer to incorporate the $ counter into the System.out.printf line rather than using a string builder or something but if it cant be done then it cant be done.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more when and where exactly you want to put the `$` signs? I can't really bring "count the number of doubles" and "in front of" in accordance with your example.

Comment: I want the $ directly after the double from the array

a simpler example I guess is if the array holds
{3.5,3.6,3.8}

Id want to output 
3.5 $
3.6 $
3.7 
3.8 $
@MichelK

Comment: Because 3.5 and 5.5 appear twice in the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Addition to Harshal Parekh's answer: if you want to use `System.out.printf`, you can use `String.repeat` instead of a while loop and a `StringBuilder`:

```
System.out.printf("%.1f %s%n", i, "$".repeat(count));
```

To compute the count value, you can use a simple for loop:

```
int count = 0;
for (double v : dubArray) {
    if (Math.abs(i - v) < 1e-5) {
        count++;
    }
}
```

Using `Math.abs(i - v) < 1e-5` introduces a bit of numerical tolerance which is always a good idea with doubles. Note that using a for loop is inefficient and there are much faster approaches, for example using hash map like in Harshal Parekh's answer.

Comment: Yes. I mentioned your answer as a more efficient alternative.

Answer (score 1):

```
double[] dubArray = {3.5, 3.5, 3.7, 4.3, 4.5, 4.5, 4.5, 4.7, 5.0, 5.5, 5.5};

// O(nlogn)
Map<Double, Integer> treeMap = new TreeMap<>();
Arrays.stream(dubArray).forEach(d -> treeMap.put(d, treeMap.getOrDefault(d, 0) + 1));

// O(n)
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
treeMap.forEach((d, f) -> {
    sb.setLength(0);
    while (f-- > 0) {
        sb.append("$");
    }
    System.out.println(d + " " + sb);
});
```

Add the elements to a `TreeMap` (my approach instead of sorting) with key as the element and the value as the frequency.

Iterate on the `TreeMap` again and generate the `$` string based on the value of the frequency and print out the result.

```
// Output
3.5 $$
3.7 $
4.3 $
4.5 $$$
4.7 $
5.0 $
5.5 $$
```

---

You don't always need to build the `$` string. You can also store that into a `HashMap`.

```
Map<Integer, String> dollarSignMap = new HashMap<>();

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
treeMap.forEach((d, f) -> {
    if (dollarSignMap.containsKey(f)) {
        System.out.println(d + " " + dollarSignMap.get(f));
    } else {
        sb.setLength(0);
        while (f-- > 0) {
            sb.append("$");
        }
        dollarSignMap.put(f, sb.toString());
        System.out.println(d + " " + sb);
    }
});
```